# Creating lots of user controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, separation-of-concerns

Is it normal in a WPF app to create a lot of user controls in order to separate concerns that would otherwise be crammed in a single window with a huge XAML hierarchy? I'm finding that I keep making new user controls, even though I don't intend to reuse them, just so that each of my sub-components has a separate task. I'm also giving each of them their own view model, instead of binding things to properties on one master view model.

Is this normal? I feel like from a code cleanliness perspective I'm doing the right thing. But from a WPF perspective, I feel that this can't be right.

For example, let's say you have a list on the left side of the window, and when you select an item, it changes what's displayed on the right side. There are also buttons above your list to manipulate it, adding and deleting items for example. I would be inclined to pull that whole list out as a UserControl, which would contain just the list and the control buttons above it. Then the main window would just include my new control.

Am I going overboard?

Comment: You can consider these usercontrols as independent Views. I see a view as an independent unit that displays some particular data and allow the user to perform actions related to that data. I think your approach (as in your left side / right side example) is OK.

Comment: I agree with HighCore. I'm developing a WPF application the same way like you and I do the same.